# PowerBI DAX: weighted average inventory pricing

Tags: powerbi, dax

I am creating an inventory model that calculates the weighted price and volume on a daily basis. I am currently able to recreate the concept in Excel (see below), but I am stuck in Power BI due to lack of recursion.

As an example, we have the following purchases and sales. We buy and sell for a total of 2,300 tons.

[image]

[image]

The objective is then to create the following table. The weighted buy price is updated for each new purchase.

- For the first purchase, its easy, as we just take the buy price of the transaction.
- For the second purchase, we calculate the new weighted buy price as:

price of inventory at T - 1 * (Inventory volume on T-1/(Inventory volume on T-1 + purchase volume at time T) + price of new purchase at time T * (purchase volume at time T/(Inventory volume on T-1 + purchase volume at time T)

With numbers (highlighted in orange below): $850 * (300 / (300 + 1,100)) + $900 * (1,100 / (300 + 1,100) = 899

- For the third purchase: we now need to use the 899 value calculated at the previous purchase. However, while I am using simple recursion here in excel, I cannot use the same method in Power BI.

[image]

The advantage of this model is that it attributes profit and inventory values in a smoothed way over time.

Does anyone have any idea to circumvent the recursion issue?

Thanks a lot for any help!

Answer (score 0):

To do what you want, don't you do a running sum of Price * Quantity and then divide that by running sum of quantity? Just checking before I try to write something that's useless nonsense.

Comment: mmm could you elaborate with an example? Maybe I am missing something on my end but I can't make it work like this. I think as well that the effect of large purchases done some time ago that technically already left the inventory would keep on weighing on the average buy price.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out in the meantime: the easiest way to add recursion to BI is to insert a python script in PowerQuery.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).